# Alguns itens em rotate ficam diferentes, como posso corrigir?

Tags: html, css

preciso de ajuda. Alguns itens que utilizei o método transform para dar um rotate de 45 degress estão um pouco diferentes do que os outros, todos eles na mesma div. Como posso fazer para corrigi-lo?

Vou dar um exemplo com imagem para ser mais específico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Pela imagem parece que os diferentes possuem altura e largura diferentes do normal.

Coloque altura e largura iguais em todos elementos e seta display:block;

.elemento { width:200px; height:200px; display:block; }

Se não for isso, coloque o código no https://jsfiddle.net para vermos melhor.

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, valeu mesmo! :)